# Add jar libraries to jdb when debug

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I want to use jdb (command line) to debug my source. My source will use some external jar libraries (ex: ojdbc).

How to config jdb refer to external jar library?

Answer (score 1):

You can use -classpath option to pass all the classes that should be visible while debugging. You can also pass -sourcepath in case you have sources. This way you can easily access all the classes that are used by your code.